# Only print lines that are unique in the second column

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, set

I have a file (1.csv), with lines of text that look like:

```
"redostoneage",RedoStoneAge,False,7378,I love America. I love our Constitution. I hope we return to our LIBERTARIAN values!
"CelebVolger",redostoneage,False,7378,I love America. I love our Constitution. I hope we return to our LIBERTARIAN values!
"PatsyRoussel",PatsyRoussel,False,1690,Blue Libbie democrat progressive and proud of it !!
```

I only want to print (or write to a new .csv) lines where the second column (i.e. redostoneage) is not duplicated on the immediately following line(s). This would be like in unix, a *case insensitive* uniq command. No sorting necessary. So for the output I'd ideally like:

```
"redostoneage",RedoStoneAge,False,7378,I love America. I love our Constitution. I hope we return to our LIBERTARIAN values!
"PatsyRoussel",PatsyRoussel,False,1690,Blue Libbie democrat progressive and proud of it !!
```

I've seen some people do this with sets. I think I am close, but I can't get the set to function correctly:

```
lines_seen = set() # holds lines already seen
for line in open('1.csv', "r"):
    columns = line.split(',')
    if len(columns) >= 2:
        username = columns[1]
        lowercaseusername = username.lower()
        if lowercaseusername not in lines_seen: # not a duplicate
            print line.strip()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you're missing is adding to lines_seen:

```
if lowercaseusername not in lines_seen:
    lines_seen.add(lowercaseusername) # <-- facepalm here
    print line.strip()
```

You just forgot that line. I'm sure you realize *why* it's necessary: you're only ever comparing to an empty set, never adding the ones you've already printed.

Comment: Facepalm indeed. That's it. Thank you!